# How to create SPF record for multiple IPs?

Tags: email, spf

I do not find any guidelines regarding how to configure multiple IPs into an SPF record.
So far I used (for example):

```
v=spf1 ip4:180.72.100.0/24 a mx ?all
```

But now I should add another range of IPs that are allowed, e.g.

```
v=spf1 ip4:180.72.100.0/24 ip4:180.20.111.0/24 a mx ?all
```

Is the second syntax correct?
Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes the second syntax is fine.

Have you tried using the SPF wizard? 
https://www.spfwizard.net/

It can quickly generate basic and complex SPF records.

Comment: Yes I was using openspf.org but I was just unsure whether I need to comma-separate the entries or newlines... Thanks!

Comment: Yep it's just newlines in the wizard (no commas)

Comment: Open SPF wizard is not more available. "The retired SPF record wizard
For a long time we had a wizard utility to assist domain owners with creating SPF records for their domains. Unfortunately the wizard was not very sophisticated and often ended up generating overly complex or even incorrect records because of the difficulty of correctly explaining the concepts underlying SPF to an audience who simply wanted to create an SPF record quickly and did not care about the finer points. For this reason the wizard has been taken down. Please consult our page on the SPF record syntax instead"

Comment: @Demelziraptor I got 20 IPs to add. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @netizen0911 if they're within a subnet you can add the range (see in the question, the `/24` after the IP denoting the subnet), otherwise you can add them individually; leave the /24 out and just add the IPs separated with spaces `ipv4:192.168.0.1 ipv4:192.168.0.2` etc within your SPF record

Comment: They discontinued the wizard it is not longer available. Please update your post.

Comment: note that some SPF verification might fail because of too many records.

Answer (score 2):

Use CIDR notation such as `ip4:180.72.100.0/24` for the range `180.72.100.0` - `180.72.100.255`.

And you can have multiple ranges in your SPF record like so:

`v=spf1 ip4:180.72.100.0/24 ip4:180.20.111.0/24 a mx ?all`

You can use this calculator to determine the correct notation for your IP ranges:

https://account.arin.net/public/cidrCalculator

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
v=spf1 ip4:abc.de.fgh.ij ip4:klm.no.pqr.st ~all
```